# preserve changes in dynamic php meny

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, fluid

I already have a site but I want's to rebuild it because it's made with table and iframe:
www.kristofdelange.be (still the old site).
I manage to implement a php menu and i can even preserve the the fluid changes.
But the problem is that the menu resets when I go to the next page.
I would like the menu to keeps it's status when a new link is loaded.
Thank's for your response.

Comment: You need to provide more info, what have you tried, are you using a library, which one, what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

that's because your website refreshes every time someone clicks a link. You have to make sure only 1 div gets refreshed instead of the entire page. You can do this with ajax, jquery, javascript, or php.

On my very first website, this was the script that I used:

```
<?php


if (isSet($_GET['page']))
{

        if (!isSet($page)){  $page = $_GET['page']; }
            if (file_exists( $page.'.php')) {
                include( $page.'.php'); 

        } 
        else
        {
        include('404.php');
        }
}
else
{
    include('home.php');

}

?>
```

I assume we speak the same language so you should get the idea.

you have to put this in the DIV that gets replaced (I usually call it content) `<div id="content"> <my code > </div>`

If you want to use this, you have to change your hrefs too.

```
<a href="?page=contact">contact</a>
```

instead of `<a href="?page=http://www.kristofdelange.be/contact">contact</a>`

I hope this helps. Good luck!

P.s. thanks to this, your website will become faster and you can drop all the  codes in pages that get loaded. You only have to type your text and insert your pictures WITHOUT any website tags.

My contact page:

```
This is contact
```

So no more tags. Your css automatically still works for these pages. Nothing changes except what I just told you. 
]

edit: Content would be what your Iframe was on your old website.